# C Program Compilation issue involving Glib2 library?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, glib, libtool

I'm trying to compile [the following project](https://github.com/ai-ku/scode) on a remote server.

I've git cloned the project on a folder called 'scode'.

The project requires glib2 and gsl libraries. Since I'm trying to compile on a remote server, I do not have sudo privileges. So I can't use a tool to install glib2 and gsl for me.

As a result, I've manually compiled both gsl and gslib2 under the folders 'scode/gsl' and 'scode/glib'.

I've had to modify the Makefile  and add absolute paths to these directories as -I options.

Nonetheless, when I try to compile the final executable. I get the following error:

> [dyuret@psglogin scode]$ make
>
> gcc -O3 -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -std=c99 -I. -I /home-2/dyuret/scode/gsl
>   -I /home-2/dyuret/scode/glib/ `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` scode.o svec.o `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -o scode
>
> //home-2/dyuret/scode/glib/glib/libglib-2.0.la: file not recognized:
>   File format not recognized
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [scode] Error 1

I've researched the issue a bit. This [link](http://hisham.hm/2011/09/13/la-file-not-recognized-file-format-not-recognized/) looks informative but I can't quite decipher what the author is saying, as I'm not that experienced with compilers, libtools and the compilation flow in general.

Any help would be much appreciated. I've already spent some time on this issue and I haven't been able to make much progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone at my group helped me with the problem. Here're the steps he roughly carried out:

(1) Manually installed glib and additional libraries at $HOME directory - i.e. $HOME/lib, $HOME/include.

(1.1) I think he did this by './configure prefix=$HOME', 'make', 'make install'.

(2) Got rid of `pkg_config` usage, which was causing the problem I outlined originally. Here are his new CLFAGS and LIBS variables:

```
CFLAGS=-O3 -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -std=c99 -I. -I$$HOME/include -I$$HOME/include/glib-2.0 -I$$HOME/lib/glib-2.0/include
LIBS=-lglib-2.0 -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -L$$HOME/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
```

After this, the code compiled without additional problems.

Comment: You could continue to use pkg-config if you exported the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable to point to $HOME/lib/pkgconfig

Answer (score 0):

It *sounds* as if what you did in order to compile the libraries in non-default (i.e. non-system) locations was maybe wrong.

For packages using autoconf (i.e. that have a `configure` script in the source root) you're supposed to use the [`--prefix`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Default-Prefix.html) option to `./configure` to set the target location where you want the package installed.

With packages building shared libraries, it's often essential to do the `make install` step, which it sounds as if you maybe didn't do.

Sorry for being vague, these things are a bit complicated.

Comment: I did omit the make install step due to not having sudo privileges. After reading your response, I've tried the following. At the '/home-2/dyuret/scode/glib' directory, I did: "./configure --prefix /home-2/dyuret/scode/glib". And then "make". And then "make install". "make install" command finished successfully. Nonetheless, I still get the same error that I posed in the original question. (The problematic ".la" file is just a text file and I can see the following line after using the prefix option: "libdir='/home-2/dyuret/scode/glib/lib'" It used to refer to some sys directory.)